Clamav Daemon not generating scan logs
We are using clamav antivirus on our GCP instances.
We are expected to review logs generated by its daemon scan.
But the daemon is not printing any logs at file.
Blank flies are generated at /var/logs/clamav
Also, we observe below logs at clamdscan.log file
--------------------------------------
ERROR: Could not connect to clamd on LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl: No such file or directory

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Time: 0.001 sec (0 m 0 s)
Start Date: 2024:03:26 01:00:01
End Date:   2024:03:26 01:00:01
--------------------------------------

Clamav Directory

Please help on how do we achieve daemon scan logs for clamav ?

try service clamav-daemon restart and then execute freshclam again

I've had the same problem, and I haven't found a way of configuring this via Clamav.
As a workaround I've added a cron that runs the a daily scan.
...
/usr/bin/clamscan -r -i --remove / > /var/log/clamav/clamav-daily-scan.log
...

I hope this has helped you

I am not sure how this would help..
can you explain please

The verbosity of the log output seemd a little introverted to me as well :-)
So I ended up trying the following, in /etc/clamav/clamd.conf:
Debug true
LogVerbose true
LogFileMaxSize 100M

And this is what I got:
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Received POLLIN|POLLHUP on fd 4
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Got new connection, FD 9
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Received POLLIN|POLLHUP on fd 5
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> fds_poll_recv: timeout after 5 seconds
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Received POLLIN|POLLHUP on fd 9
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> got command CONTSCAN /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20241231T000616-04840-vGter1o_/parts (72, 6), argu   ment: /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20241231T000616-04840-vGter1o_/parts
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> mode -> MODE_WAITREPLY
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Breaking command loop, mode is no longer MODE_COMMAND
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Consumed entire command
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Number of file descriptors polled: 1 fds
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> fds_poll_recv: timeout after 3600 seconds
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> THRMGR: queue (single) crossed low threshold -> signaling
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> THRMGR: queue (bulk) crossed low threshold -> signaling
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Finished scanthread
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> Scanthread: connection shut down (FD 9)
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> THRMGR: queue (single) crossed low threshold -> signaling
Tue Dec 31 00:33:26 2024 -> THRMGR: queue (bulk) crossed low threshold -> signaling

Still a little underwhelming, huh :-)
Then I noticed that someone mentioned, that by default, no output goes into the log file, all output goes to stdout.
So I checked journalctl -xe, and yes, there was a wealth of output.
So I further filtered just clamd, using
journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=clamav-daemon.service

(at least that's what it's called on my system.)
Lots of output from LibClamAV debug .
Hmm. Apart from LibClamAV debug, there's just the introverted stuff that you get in the log file...
I've also noticed that journalctl knows the "-f" argument ("follow"), originally a feature of the UNIX "tail" command.
